# How to copy project folder with ansible to remote (over ssh), ignoring some files

Tags: node.js, ssh, deployment, ansible

I have my project repository.
I want to clone it and execute an ansible-playbook.
How to make ansible copy this project folder to target machine over ssh, and ignore some files/folders?
Sould i check or create the destination folder?

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved that problem with ansible synchronize_module
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html